# What's up with these dates?

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, revisions-list, timestamps

I was reviewing some edit dates on a post at PPCG when I noticed something odd:

[image]

Why are the dates formatted differently if they are on the same day? Last time I checked, the year was 2017, so why the added '17? The ones after the tweeted status don't have it.

---

<sup>Not entirely sure if this is a bug or some kind of wonky time issue. I'm not sure if something happened between 3 and 6 to warrant the change in format, but I'm tagging as bug just in case.</sup>

General information:

- App version 1.6.2.5
- iPhone 6s
- iOS 10.1.1 (Build 14B100)

Comment: Is it for iOS app only or for Android too?

Comment: [No repro here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWFJX.png). What version of he app do you have? (in future, if you tag the question `ios-app` it will auto append version info to your question)

Comment: @alexolut android app has no revisions list.

Comment: @Cai are you sure about tag? As far as I know version info appends only when posting bugs via the button "submit bug" in the app. Can't test right now though.

Comment: @ShadowWizard true. Especially for this reason tag should be `ios-app`, not `mobile-app` as added by Adam.

Comment: @alexolut true, Adam put a wrong tag. Happens. :-)

Comment: @alexolut yeh I'm sure, I never use the "submit bug" button. As long as it's tagged `ios-app` and `bug` it will append the info (can't remember if it does for `support` or `feature-request` too).

Comment: @Cai hm-m ... will try it at evening. Thanx.

Comment: I love the artstyle! <3, Is that an _Urban_ style?

Comment: @Cai Yeah. I forgot to tag as an iOS bug. Looks like it doesn't append information after the original posting. I've added some info in the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.6.3.3, shipping this month.

The problem is that we show dates in UTC time, we don't show the current year, AND while 2:28 AM UTC was in 2017 in Greenwich, it was still 2016 where you live.

I simply had to use the right calendar when extracting the year from the date.

Comment: I suspected it had something to do with my timezone. Thanks for the clarification!